# Angular 5 FormControl Attribute doesn't return values when disabled

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm creating a Reactive Form like this:

```
this.modelForm = new FormGroup({
  number: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
  otherValue1: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}),
  otherValue2: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
  detail: new FormArray([])
});
```

Now, when i try to get the current value of the form I only get:

```
this.modelForm.value => 
Object: { otherValue1: '' , detail:[] }
```

Every field with the "disabled:true" attribute is omitted from the returned object.

How do I make them being returned by that method?

Note: I disable the fields to get a coherent view with the other input forms. It look so much better and I don't think one field is an overhead to the performance

Comment: use this.modelForm.getRawValue() not this.modelForm.value, see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be due to the [definition of forms by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) (I'd expect that angular has a similar approach as "old HTML forms"). Disable an element has the following effects:

- Disabled controls do not receive focus.
- Disabled controls are skipped in tabbing navigation.
- Disabled controls cannot be successful.
- Disabled controls will not submit data.

This "should" be enforced by the browser. You should instead use the [Raw Values](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue) in angular which will ignore the disabled status.

Comment: Parden my ignorance here, but doesn't this feel a little short-sighted from a usage standpoint. Learning the reactive form layer of Angular and having to deal with the W3C specs for form input fields feels like a recipe for a lot of issues rather than giving back what the end user would most likely expect back which is the "value". regardless of a disabled state. Most likely this would be better brought up to the angular team on GitHub.. But interesting either way. Thanks for giving the info here.